# multiple ascx wont show using ng-if

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, webforms, user-controls

I'm using angularjs at my old website. And I have a problem with getting ng-if to work with multiple controls.

I have 2 icons, when I press icon A then user control A shows, when I press icon B, user control B doesn't show up.

It works if I change the order of the divs (so that user control B) is the first, but then user control A wont work. So the second one never does...

I tried remove the div containing user control A, and then user control B shows up.

I have validated so that all the booleans are correct.

I have debugged and can see that `vm.showControlBisVisible` is true, and I can see that the showControlAreaVisible shows up, but *not* the ascx file.

And last, the User Controls have exactly the same code, except for a different -tag.

**EDIT:** If I remove the ng-if attribute and put for example ng-if="true" then it works. Could it be that the scope doesnt update the value in the DOM or something like that? If I just write out `{{vm.showControlBisVisible}}` I get true.

My .aspx:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/MyPage/UserControls/UserControlA.ascx" TagPrefix="MyPage" TagName="ControlA" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/MyPage/UserControls/UserControlB.ascx" TagPrefix="MyPage" TagName="ControlB" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMainRegion" runat="server">
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm">            

    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-6 columns text-center">
                        <a ng-click="vm.showControlA()">
                            <span class="sprite">
                                <ng-include src="'/MyPage/Assets/svg/icon-A.svg'"></ng-include>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="small-6 columns text-center">
                        <a ng-click="vm.showControlB()">
                            <span class="sprite">
                                <ng-include src="'/MyPage/Assets/svg/icon-B.svg'"></ng-include>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section--content section--gray" id="content-area" ng-show="vm.showControlAreaVisible">
        <div ng-if="vm.controlAisVisible">     
            <MyPage:ControlA runat="server" />            
        </div>
        <div ng-if="vm.controlBisVisible">      
            <MyPage:ControlB runat="server" />            
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

My controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function MyController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.showControlAreaVisible = false;
    vm.controlAisVisible = false;
    vm.controlBisVisible = false;

    vm.showControlA = showControlA;
    vm.showControlB = showControlB;

    function showControlA() {
        vm.controlBisVisible = false;

        vm.showControlAreaVisible = true;
        vm.controlAisVisible = true;
    }

    function showControlB() {
        vm.controlAisVisible = false;

        vm.showControlAreaVisible = true;
        vm.controlBisVisible = true;
    }

}
})();
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the console? Are you sure that controls are being rendered correctly (i.e. no closing tags missing)? Try replacing controls with some simple html stub, would it work? I have tried to run this code and it seems working.

Comment: The error, what I can see, is that the `vm.controlBisVisible` is set to true, but the div is treated like its false when checking the DOM